# JQuery "parsererror" when trying to use Ajax in IE 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-6

When using jQuery Ajax, I am receiving a parseerror in IE 6, Firefox works just fine.

My code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'test.xml',
   type: 'GET',
   dataType: 'xml',

   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert('Error: ' + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
   },

   success: function(xml){
        ...
   }
});
```

The output is "Error: parsererror, undefined"

Comment: Perhaps the xml isn't well structured. Could you provide it?

Comment: No... i've tried with several XML and all give the same error. It happened even with the simpler XML... like: <test></test>

Comment: I'm also having this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this happens when I execute the code in localhost. When I upload the code to the remote server works OK.

Answer (score 1):

Just a shot in the dark, but what happens whan you rename the XMLHttpRequest argument?